# How can I restore my landing page content?

Tags: bug, design, interesting-page

Before a [recent change,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1) visiting `https://stackoverflow.com/` displayed "interesting" questions *with excerpts*. Now excerpts are gone, and the page is pretty much useless.

If I visit `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` (the "Questions" link in the left nav), excerpts are displayed, but I don't see a tab for "interesting" in that view.

What URL can I visit to obtain the same content I had before this change?

---

Update: Even in the unlikely case that my timeline has somehow collided with one where excerpts on the home page didn't exist, my question remains. How can I have excepts for interesting questions?

Comment: Same here, the new design does not look like an improvement.

Comment: Personally I use `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20intags%3amine` to display a search view for questions on my watched tags.

Comment: @greg-449 Does that strictly limit to watched tags? Or does it include interesting questions based on one's history?

Comment: @erickson It is strictly watched tags, nothing else

Comment: _"displayed "interesting" questions with excerpts."_ Wait, what? I'm pretty sure no excerpts were displayed on the landing page (only on /questions). Edit: Isn't [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7rtT.png) how the landing page looked like before?

Comment: There definitely were excerpts. It must have varied from user to user somehow. I used to get excerpts on the landing page, too, exactly as erickson describes. It was a filtered version of [`/questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but less filtered than greg's suggestion of only watched questions.

Comment: Huh! I never ever seen excerpts there and never knew that other users did. Weird!

Comment: This post is actually restoring my sanity. I felt like I've been getting gaslit with everyone insisting there were no excerpts and posting archive.org links showing none. I *know* they were there; not on any sub-page but right on the home page `https://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: I'm having another Berenstein Bears moment. The multiverse is a crazy place. I think the only way I can really be convinced they were never there is with a rollback.

Comment: I must admit that this post is driving me nuts. Now I really don't know if there were excerpts in the (or my) home page or not. Without them definitely looks "wrong", like there is something missing. Are we part of a social experiment here?

Answer (score 2):

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=RecentActivity&tagMode=Watched&uqlId=53695`

This sorts by "Active" and filters for tags you watch. Not an exact replacement as there is no suggestion algorithm involved, which may or may not be a bad thing.

Comment: ...until the new design is also applied to /questions and then the only option would be to use a userscript (which won't work in all situations).